# How to make your displayed data vary once this form pops up again?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, xampp

I am new to VB.net and I really had a hard time to this problem. I want to fetch all rows where the statement is "Logical Reasoning" by displaying it one by one in my richtextbox and radio buttons once this form show up again through next button. I am using xampp for my database and visual studio vb.net. I hope you can help me with this. Thank you in advance. Here is my code in my database connection module:

````
    Private dbConn As New MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=quiz;Convert Zero DateTime=True")
    Private qreader As MySqlDataReader
    Private cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand

    Public Sub displayData(ByRef richText As RichTextBox, ByRef radiobtnA As RadioButton, ByRef radiobtnB As RadioButton, ByRef radiobtnC As RadioButton, ByRef radiobtnD As RadioButton, ByRef sql As String)
        Try
            cmd.Connection = dbConn
            openConnection()
            cmd.CommandText = sql
            qreader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

            While qreader.Read
                richText.Text = (qreader("Question").ToString)
                radiobtnA.Text = (qreader("Choice A").ToString)
                radiobtnB.Text = (qreader("Choice B").ToString)
                radiobtnC.Text = (qreader("Choice C").ToString)
                radiobtnD.Text = (qreader("Choice D").ToString)
            End While

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        End Try
        qreader.Close()
        closeConnection()
    End Sub
    ReadOnly Property getConnection() As MySqlConnection
        Get
            Return dbConn
        End Get
    End Property

    Sub openConnection()
        If dbConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            dbConn.Open()
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub closeConnection()
        If dbConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            dbConn.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
End Module ```



Here is the code in my form that I want to display the data with:

```Public Class quizForm
    Dim sql As String

Private Sub quizForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        sql = "SELECT * FROM `examquestion` WHERE `Exam Category` = 'Logical Reasoning'"
        displayData(rtxtQuestion, rbnA, rbnB, rbnC, rbnD, sql)

    End Sub```

The code is working but only displayed the first row of category Logical Reasoning.
````

Comment: Query the database and populate a `DataTable`, bind that to a `BindingSource` and bind that to your controls. You can then navigate the data by calling `MoveNext` and `MovePrevious` on the `BindingSource`.

Comment: Why us a `RichTextBox` for plain text? Why not just use a `Textbox`?

Comment: @John I've just tried your suggestion but I get an error saying "ADP_ConnectionRequired_Fill" how can I fix it? If you would still want to help. I'm sorry, I'm really new to this and I don't have much time to learn

Comment: here is the updated code btw    ```Public Class quizForm

    Dim index As Integer = 0
    Dim table As New DataTable() 
    
    Public Sub showData(position As Integer)
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `examquestion` WHERE `Exam Category` = 'Logical Reasoning'")
        Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(command)

Comment: ` table.Clear()
        adapter.Fill(table)
        lblNum.Text = table.Rows(position)(0).ToString()
        rtxtQuestion.Text = table.Rows(position)(1).ToString()
        rbnA.Text = table.Rows(position)(2).ToString()
        rbnB.Text = table.Rows(position)(3).ToString()
        rbnC.Text = table.Rows(position)(4).ToString()
        rbnD.Text = table.Rows(position)(5).ToString()
    End Sub`

Comment: Private Sub logicalReasoning_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        showData(index)
    End Sub                                                                                                                  
 Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
        'logicalTimer.Stop()
        index += 1
        showData(index)                                          Private Sub btnPrevious_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click
        index -= 1
        showData(index)
    End Sub
    End Sub

Comment: Don't post loads of code in comments. It's basically unreadable. Edit the question or, if the question is different now, post a new question.